# GGA functionals requiring second derivatives?

Tags: density-functional-theory

In ["Lecture Notes in Quantum Chemistry II" from the European Summer School in Quantum Chemistry](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-57890-8), the authors note that when discussing the LYP functional and other GGA functionals, that

> Thus one can immediately see that an evaluation of $v_{xc}$ demands an evaluation fo the second derivatives of basis functions.
> (pp102).

Indeed, when (for a functional like B88) I start with the functional itself and compute the functional derivative (either by hand or with a CAS), I arrive at a (messy) expression that involves second derivatives with respect to space. However, [libraries like libxc](https://www.tddft.org/programs/libxc/manual/) only need scalar functions of the gradient to be passed, in particular $\nabla \rho \cdot \nabla \rho$ , in order to compute $v_{xc}$. Now libxc contains the expressions for its functionals in Maple and then performs symbolic differentiation on them and then uses the maple-to-C translator; thus the actual C code in libxc is uninterpretable by a human.

Is there a known expression for $v_{xc}$ for B88 or another GGA-like functional that might give me a hint as to how to simplify the functional derivative to only depend on these parameters?

Comment: The [NWChem code](https://github.com/nwchemgit/nwchem/tree/master/src/nwxc) for PW91 and B88 looks handwritten and may be understandable. I do not have the papers at hand, so I cannot judge.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my original reference is now somewhat out of date, and it is quite possible to compute the relevant properties without resorting to second spatial derivatives. [Johnson1993] has a nice overview of the relevant math, including clean derivations of both YLP and B88 functional terms, and states:

> Note that Eq. (7) does not require evaluation of the spin density second de- rivatives as is necessary in many other formulations, a major computational advantage [48]. The fact that these can be avoided has been previously noted by Kobayashi et al.

Johnson, B. G., Gill, P. M. W., & Pople, J. A. (1993). The performance of a family of density functional methods. The Journal of Chemical Physics, 98(7), 5612–5626. https://doi.org/10.1063/1.464906

and

Kobayashi, K., Kurita, N., Kumahora, H., & Tago, K. (1991). Bond-Energy calculations of Cu2, Ag2, and CuAg with the generalized gradient approximation. Physical Review A, 43(11), 5810–5813. https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.43.5810